# How to make Wordpress theme editable by other users

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, blogs, wordpress-theming

I have installed a Wordpress theme in /wp-content/themes/mytheme/
I then applied this theme to a specific site. I am using Wordpress multi-site.
I want users who have access to the site to also be able to edit the theme from Wordpress.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, only the super-admin has the ability to edit theme files in the WordPress multisite environment.  In order to circumvent this default behavior, you will need to build and install a  simple plugin and modify a WordPress core file.  Instructions for doing so can be found [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/multisite-theme-edit).  Posts by jroakes and jrue contain the code you need to make the modifications.  Keep in mind that updating WordPress could break the modification.  Also be aware of the security risks involved.